# 2D Game: Collision Detection fails if FPS below 20

Tags: javascript, loops, frame-rate

So I just changed my game update function to update alle movements depending on the difference between the actual FPS and the fixed game FPS.

For example I set my game to a fixed `60` FPS.
If the actual FPS is `20` I calculate the difference like that:

`((20 * 100) / 60) / 100` which would result in `0.333`
So the difference of `1` game loop would be `1 - 0.333 = 0.677`

Thus all game movements wouldn't be updated based on a normal game loop:

`x += speedX * 1` but width an increased value: `x += speedX * 1.677`

So now my game runs at the same speed on every system, just with less pictures, but thats not the problem.

I'm not entirely sure if that causes the collisoin detection to fail, but I guess as the game speed gets increased to match the current fps, the collision detection isn't able to track all events anymore because positions get skipped. It will only check for collision around the player.

How do I manage this problem ?

**Edit:**

Here is an example of the collision detection:

```
var xi = this._game.level.getField(this.x);
var yi = this._game.level.getField(this.y);

var left = this._game.level.levelData["col"][(xi-1) + "," + yi] ? (xi-1) * 32 : null;
var right = this._game.level.levelData["col"][(xi+1) + "," + yi] ? (xi+1) * 32 : null;
var top = this._game.level.levelData["col"][xi + "," + (yi-1)] ? (yi-1) * 32 : null;
var bottom = this._game.level.levelData["col"][xi + "," + (yi+1)] ? (yi+1) * 32 : null;

// Will hit ground ?
if (this.y + this.height >= bottom && bottom != null) {
    this.ground = true;
    if (!this.jumping) this.y = bottom - this.height;
}

// Left
if (this.x <= left + 32 && left != null) {
    this.x = left + 32;
}

// Right
if (this.x + this.width >= right && right != null) {
    this.x = right - this.width;
}
```

`this` is the player.
and `left/right` are the collision tile positions on the grid.
Each tile is 32x32 and the player is 25x25.

Here is the full game: [removed]

**Edit:** The problem is actually somewhere else since bottom is not null.
When I put the player at `bottom - (this.height + 1)` instead of `bottom - this.height` (1 pixel higher), he doesn't allways fall through.

Comment: you are doing it wrong. change LOD of objects that collide and don't mess with time.

Comment: @fazo What are you talking about? Almost all game loops adjust for time. That's the basis of framerate independent animation

Comment: LOD = Level Of Detail ? It's just a 2D HTML5 Game: http://elias-schuett.de/canvas/iwbtg/

Comment: @elias94xx what does your collision detection algorithm look like? Is it just simple " do these two things overlap *right now*?"

Comment: @32bitkid I edited my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im on my phone right now so I can't check out your sample. So if I am reading your collision detection stuff right, then you update the players position and then check for a collision. This, if the frame rate is low enough or the object is moving fast enough, means that an object can "phase" right through a barrier. Being entirely on one side of it before the frame update and being entirely on the opposite side of it after the frame update.

There are a couple ways to address this problem, the most direct is to not only test where the object is *now*, but where it's been as well while it moved. Implement a collision detection algorithm that detects all the zones that a player or object has to pass through to get from a to b and base your collision on that.

Also checkout gamedev.stackexchange.com. It's usually a good place to ask game specific questions.

Comment: I do actually only move the object if it's current position doesn't collide with anything. If it does collide on the next check, the position will be corrected. You are probably right, that the object passes through the barrier when the game updates faster. Your ideas were roughly on my mind already, just wanted to make sure I'm choosing the best way. I'll try and implement the algorithm now, thanks!

Comment: One way around the problem is to enforce a minimum physics time step. If you want to enforce a 60Hz physics simulation and you're at 20 fps, then you step the physics three times in one frame at 1/3rd of the 20 fps frame time. Of course, this extra work being done by the physics update can further lower your framerate, this is called a "well of dispair" problem. Usually you can clamp the number of extra framesteps to about 3 so your framerate won't lower much by the extra steps.